# How to password_verify() with hash from database

Tags: php, mysql, passwords

Attempting to verify the hash password from the database, with the user input via POST. After some brief research it seems the issue may have something to do with not being able to convert the mysqli_query to a string though I do not know how to do that properly, hence the fetch_object() etc which I added from another SO question. I have also adequately accounted for the length of the has with the column set for varchar(255). Appreciate any help or guidance, thanks.

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "test";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$password = $_POST['password'];
$db_password = mysqli_query($conn, 'SELECT password FROM sec')->fetch_object()->password;

if (password_verify($password, $db_password)) {
    echo 'Password is valid!';
} else {
    echo 'Invalid password.';
}
?>
```

Comment: @martinstoeckli oh my God you're right, I was thinking of something else. I'm sorry, I'll remove the comments so it won't confuse OP.

Comment: Assuming that every user has its own password, your SQL statement seems to be wrong: `SELECT password FROM sec` this searches all passwords from table sec. Instead you probably want to search for the given user, something like this: `SELECT password FROM sec WHERE username = ?`.

Comment: Anyway, despite of it, it's still good if you can dump your `$db_password`. If that query is even working, you're probably receiving an array/obj of results, and not a single string.

Comment: Thanks @martinstoeckli there is only one row in this particular table and thus echoing $db_password does provide the correct string as expected.

Comment: @masteryupa - So did you do a `var_dump($db_password)` and a `var_dump($password)`? Did they have the correct datatype and the correct length and aren't there any whitespaces?

Comment: @martinstoeckli - Per your instructions I have found that there is actually a single space at the end of the database hash, not sure why but how would I go about removing that if it is in fact the problem?

Comment: @masteryupa - I would have a look at the storing procedure, maybe the blank was added there? Better not to have it in the database at all.

Comment: @martinstoeckli - Must have been an earlier error on my part which is frustrating but thanks for helping me find it!

Answer (score 1):

First get the password hash from the database,then convert the user input password in the hash value.Compare these two values by passing through the function password_verify(), then you will get the proper result.

Answer (score 0):

```
    $password = "test";

    $hash = "$2y$10$fXJEsC0zWAR2tDrmlJgSaecbKyiEOK9GDCRKDReYM8gH2bG2mbO4e";



    if (password_verify($password, $hash)) {
        echo "Success";
    }
    else {
        echo "Error";
    }

OR
You can use this one too
$verify=password_verify($_POST['passwrd'],$row[2]);

if($verify){
    $_SESSION["usrname"]=$usrname;
    echo "Correct";
}
else {
    echo "user: " . $usrname. "<br>";
    echo "pass: " . $hash. "<br>";
    echo "db: " . $row[2]."<br>";
    echo "Wrong Username or Password";
}
```

Comment: I don't think the password_verify() function is the problem, it is used correctly by the OP.